# Проверьте правильность написания if

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, if

Взгляните на код нуба и оцените насколько правильно я написал условие ИФ, я долго мучался и у меня не срабатывал последний ПРИНТ. В итоге мне сам Питон исправил мой ИФ. Но как мне сказали мои коллеги, что че-то очень заморочено написано.

Подскажите и дайте критику начинающему.

Задача:

- Создайте программу медицинская анкета, где вы запросите у пользователя такие данные, как имя, фамилию, возраст, и вес.
- И выведите результат согласно которому пациент в хорошем состоянии, если ему до 30 лет и вес от 50 и до 120 кг,
- Пациенту требуется начать вести правильный образ жизни, если ему более 30 и вес меньше 50 или больше 120 кг
- Пациенту требуется врачебный осмотр, если ему более 40 и вес менее 50 или больше 120 кг.
- Все остальные варианты вы можете обработать на ваш вкус и полет фантазии =)

Мое решение:

```
a = str (input("name:"))
b = str (input("first_name:"))
c = int (input("age:"))
d = int (input("weight:"))


if not (not (c <= 30 and d >= 50 <= 120) and not (c > 30 and d < 50 > 120) 
and not  (c>=40 and d <50 >120)):
print("пациент в хорошем состоянии") #если ему до 30 лет и вес от 50 и до 
120 кг,
elif 41 > c >30:
print("Пациенту требуется начать вести правильный образ жизни") #если ему 
более 30 и вес меньше 50 или больше 120 кг
elif c>40:
print("Пациенту требуется врачебный осмотр")                    #если ему 
более 40 и вес менее 50 или больше 120 кг.
```

Comment: Ерунда какая-то. ``d >= 50 <= 120`` - что здесь проверяется? И здесь: ``d < 50 > 120``.

Comment: Тут много чему можно дать совет... Например, 1) имя -- first_name, фамилия -- second_name. 2) Избавьтесь от однобуквенных переменных, дайти им названия по их назначению: `first_name`, `second_name`, `age`, `weight` 3) `str(input(...))` бессмысленная конструкция -- `input()` и так возвращает строку

Comment: @Эникейщик вот это условие: если ему до 30 лет и вес от 50 и до 120 кг

Comment: @Антон, у вас питон2 что ли? :) Тогда не input вызывайте а `raw_input`

Comment: "вот это условие: если ему до 30 лет и вес от 50 и до 120 кг " - нет, там проверяется не это. И вообще, коллеги правы. Не нужно запихивать в один ``if`` такую громоздку непонятную конструцию (к тому же с двумя ``not`` подряд).

Comment: @gil9red не я просто не то убрал =))) вместо str убрал int =))

Comment: Так и я чувствую что простыня огромная, как лучше-то? я все перепробовал.

Answer (score 4):

Если писать условия прямо по шагам задания:

```
first_name = input("first name: ")
second_name = input("second name: ")
age = int(input("age: "))
weight = int(input("weight: "))

# "...если ему до 30 лет и вес от 50 и до 120 кг..."
if age < 30 and 50 <= weight <= 120:
    print("Пациент в хорошем состоянии")

# "...если ему более 30 и вес меньше 50 или больше 120 кг..."
elif 30 < age <= 40 and (weight < 50 or weight > 120):
    print("Пациенту требуется начать вести правильный образ жизни")

# "...если ему более 40 и вес менее 50 или больше 120..."
elif age > 40 and (weight < 50 or weight > 120):
    print("Пациенту требуется врачебный осмотр")

else:
    print("Пациент в удовлетворительном состоянии")
```

---

**PS.**

- Чтобы ввод имени и фамилии не казался бесполезным занятием, можно вывести их в результатах, например:

  ```
  print("Пациент '{} {}' в хорошем состоянии".format(second_name, first_name))
  ```

  или через f-строки:

  ```
  print(f"Пациент '{second_name} {first_name}' в хорошем состоянии")
  ```
- Меня в условии немного путало указание возраста/веса, например непонятно при указании диапазона, нужно ли включали или исключать возраст/вес.
- Для `elif 30 < age <= 40`  условие имеет ограничение из-за того, что нужно правильно обработать условие с `elif age > 40`. Можно было не городить ограничение, а просто поменять местами проверки:

  ```
  ...
  # "...если ему более 40 и вес менее 50 или больше 120..."
  elif age > 40 and (weight < 50 or weight > 120):
      print("Пациенту требуется врачебный осмотр")

  # "...если ему более 30 и вес меньше 50 или больше 120 кг..."
  elif age > 30 and (weight < 50 or weight > 120):
      print("Пациенту требуется начать вести правильный образ жизни")
  ```

  Либо, объединить условия по ограничению веса и внутри условия проверять возраст

Comment: во, у Вас как то грамотней получилось. Спасибо, я учту и буду возвращаться к Вашему примеру.
P.S. У меня последний пайтон, 3.

Comment: @Антон, тогда примите мой ответ :)